# Tails without desktop

Tags: tails

How can I get a version of Tails (Tails or TAILS?) without the desktop GUI environment installed? If I can't, then how can I manually uninstall the desktop?

Comment: Can clarify why you want/need this? You can load a terminal once Tails is booted if you need command-line utilities.

Comment: why would you want to do this? It removes most of the OS's key features' functionality. you would have to build a headless linux distro and then compile first as the os isn't persistant once you put it on a usb.

Comment: To answer your question, it doesn't remove functionality for someone who is experienced with the console. In response to you second remark, TAILS is based off of Debian, and I have personally used a non-desktop version of that operating system.

Comment: I want this because I am thinking of running an onion site and want a secure, anonymous server.

Comment: I stumbled across [this table](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Comparison_with_Others#Attacks) on the whonix website, which says that `Tails is not meant to be used as a server (yet).` Is seems to be true, I have never come across Tails without a GUI, and when I tried to log into a virtual console, root can't log in and it wouldn't let me log in as amnesia (even though I made a password and could open a root terminal in the GUI) that could cause a problem if you do manage to uninstall the GUI. Right now I don't think you can do this using the ISO from the website not in a way it still works.

Comment: There is a tails server version I don't know if it is official or not [Server Link](https://tails.boum.org/blueprint/tails_server/). Also I don't know if you can download it or not yet. If you don't want to go that route with a tails server you could do `sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell gnome-desktop`
I haven't tested this yet so I don't know exactly which gnome version they are using so you might have to search through your installed packages and remove it.

Comment: `apt-get remove ...` is not actually going to be helpful. You can uninstall the desktop but the next time you reboot, it'll be reinstalled. Tails Server will come with a GUI for use with the desktop for setting up specific services that might be useful, it's not ready for download yet and won't do what they're expecting. If you want to swap to a tty press ctrl+alt+f{1..6}.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it seems not possible to do this. Tails is thought to be a live operating system for an end user. While you can remove all the GUI features (`apt purge …`), they'll be present at the next reboot.

As [one of the commenters](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9153/tails-without-desktop#comment12317_9153) wrote tails is thinking about a [tails server](https://tails.boum.org/blueprint/tails_server/). If they realise this feature, you'll be able to use it headless as a secure server.

However at the moment you can't get such a version of tails.